# Currfile and acutes

Tags: currfile

I'm currently working on a document with LaTeX and I want to make all sectioning in a separate document.

On main.tex I have the following

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, fonttype=arial]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[catalan, activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{currfile}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\input{Composició de la matèria}
%On the future I will have more \input with more sections

\end{document}
```

And on "Composició de la matèria.tex" I have this

```
\section{\currfilebase}
%On the future I will have more text here
```

But the pdf output it's the following

Table of contents
[image: Table of contents, has the proper output]

The section
[image: The section, doesn't have the proper output]

It happens with all the catalan acutes, how could I do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is an interesting idea, but is it really necessary that the file name is exactly the section title in the file? Just being curious ...

Comment: I wouldn't do that, file names and section titles are quite different things and should be set independantly. What will you do if you want a superscript or some math or some latex command in the title ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's much to gain with this approach.

Anyway, the problem is that `\currfilebase` is stored as a string (all characters receive category code 12) and so `utf8` cannot do its translation job.

Here's a patch that also stores a “normal characters” version of `\currfilebase`, called `\utfcurrfilebase`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\currfile@set}
 {\global\let\currfilebase\filename@base}
 {\global\let\currfilebase\filename@base\makeutf@currfilebase}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:cpn { makeutf@currfilebase }
 {
  \tl_gset_rescan:Nnx \utfcurrfilebase {} { \currfilebase }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\input{Composició de la matèria}

\end{document}
```

The included file should use `\utfcurrfilebase`:

```
\section{\utfcurrfilebase}
```

[image]